# Mapping a string to a unique number?

Tags: c++, bash, awk

Is there a nice bash one liner to map strings inside a file to a unique number?

For instance,

```
a
a
b
b
c
c
```

should be converted into

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

I am currently implementing it in C++ but a bash one-liner would be great.

Comment: Does your file only contain one character strings?

Comment: Are we talking about single lower-case character strings only?

Comment: @csj: Actually they are hash strings. @tangens: alpha-numeric to be precise but one string in a line

Comment: 1. Your example suggests you have specific numeric representations in mind. Is that the case, or are you only concerned with ensuring that the number is unique? 2. Do your hash strings have a maximum length? 3. Do the numeric representations have a maximum required length?

Comment: @csj: The maximum length is 40 characters. All I need is for the sam number to be mapped again back to the string if it is seen again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
awk '{if (!($0 in ids)) ids[$0] = ++i; print ids[$0]}'
```

This maintains an associative array called `ids`. Each time it finds a new string it assigns it a monotically increasing id `++i`.

Example:

```
jkugelman$ echo $'a\nb\nc\na\nb\nc' | awk '{if (!($0 in ids)) ids[$0] = ++i; print ids[$0]}'
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

Comment: Awesome... Thanks! Just finished my C++ version too :)

Comment: Nice one! You beat me to it *and* did it in one line. +1 for showing me that you don't have to initialize a variable in Awk.

Comment: Come to think of it, in my solution I used the `seen` variable unitialized, without even thinking about it...

Answer (score 3):

The awk solutions here are fine, but here's the same approach in pure bash (>=4)

```
declare -A stringmap
counter=0
while read string < INPUTFILE; do
    if [[ -z ${stringmap[$string]} ]]; then
        let counter+=1
        stringmap[$string]=$counter
    fi
done
for string in "${!stringmap[@]}"; do
    printf "%d -> %s\n" "${stringmap[$string]}" "$string"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'BEGIN { num = 0; }
{
    if ($0 in seen) {
        print seen[$0];
    } else {
        seen[$0] = ++num;
        print num;
    }
}' [file]
```

(Not exactly one line, ofcourse.)

Comment: Yeah true but that makes it more legible :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

slight modification without the `if`

```
awk '!($0 in ids){ids[$0]=++i}{print ids[$0]}' file
```